# Get filename without Content-Disposition

Tags: c#, header, webclient, content-disposition

I am looking for a solution for this problem for days and I can't find any.

I want to download a file from a webserver with a webclient. The download works fine, but I can't  get the real filename, which is very important for me.

I read on many homepages, that the filename should be saved in the Content-Disposition-Header. Unfortunately this header of the site is empty. I tried to get it with:

```
string header_contentDisposition ="";
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
                client.OpenRead(link);

                header_contentDisposition = client.ResponseHeaders["Content-Disposition"];
                MessageBox.Show(header_contentDisposition);
            }
```

There is no information saved inside this header.

If I try to download the file with my Browser (IE, Opera, Chrome) the filename gets shown in the filedialog, so it has to be saved somewhere.

Can you imagine where I can find it?

EDIT: I can't extract it from the URL, because the link is generated by php like

```
http://www.example.com/download.php?id=10
```

Comment: Can you dump the headers which *are* present? Or perhaps browsers are defaulting it from the URL?

Comment: All headers I got:

Age = 292161
Connection=keep-alive
Accept-Ranges=bytes
Content-Length=15953830
Cache-Control=max-age=31536000
Content-Type=application/vnd.android.package-archive
Date=Fri, 23 Nov 2012 09:21:40 GMT
Expires=Sat, 23 Nov 2013 09:21:40 GMT
Last-Modified=Fri, 23 Nov 2012 08:38:35 GMT
Server=nginx

Comment: Can you give us a real URL so we can reproduce this?

Comment: for example:

http://upload.p-kratzer.com/index.php?dir=&file=GE.JPG

of course, in this particular case i could get the filename from the "file" parameter, but I have to download from different servers and often that's not possible

Comment: Rather than giving an example which *isn't* representative of the problem, why don't you give us one which *is*? i.e. a URL where: 1) The filename isn't in the URL; 2) The filename isn't in the Content-Dispoition; 3) Browsers still manage to download the file correctly.

Comment: here it is:http://upload.p-kratzer.com/index.php?dir=&file=asdfasdfwervdcvvedb

 (the real file name should be "wetter.JPG")

Comment: @user1854270: That's just a redirect.

Comment: What I would do is use the debugger, and see what the content of your response is, and see if anything that looks like a filename is in there

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can try this:

```
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        try
        {

            HttpWebResponse res = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            using (Stream rstream = res.GetResponseStream())
            {
                string fileName = res.Headers["Content-Disposition"] != null ?
                    res.Headers["Content-Disposition"].Replace("attachment; filename=", "").Replace("\"", "") :
                    res.Headers["Location"] != null ? Path.GetFileName(res.Headers["Location"]) : 
                    Path.GetFileName(url).Contains('?') || Path.GetFileName(url).Contains('=') ?
                    Path.GetFileName(res.ResponseUri.ToString()) : defaultFileName;
            }
            res.Close();
        }
        catch { }
```

Tested this on http://upload.p-kratzer.com/index.php?dir=&file=asdfasdfwervdcvvedb and it does return wetter.JPG.

Comment: Great Lunyx. Thank you. But when i use this for google drive links get a big result string. For example "attachment;filename=filename.apk;filename*=UTF-8''filename.apk"

Comment: @smedasn Probably the space between `attachment;` and `filename=` is missing in the header Google drive supplies. It's not required by the standard, so you should handle that case.