# Detect file type uploaded in discord.net

Tags: c#, discord, discord.net

I'm writing a Discord bot in C# using the Discord.Net library. I've got a working bot and it scans messages and deletes those containing the text "gif" "giphy" etc. This removes all links to gifs that Discord automatically embeds. However, a directly uploaded .gif file is not detected.

I'd like a method of, when a file is uploaded to a Discord text channel, receiving the type of that file, preferably in string format like "txt" or "png" etc.

Comment: Have you perhaps checked the Attachment#Url property?

Comment: @Still how would I go about doing this? I've tried using Context.Message.Attachments, Message.Attatchments, and MessageParam.Attatchments but it always returns the same thing no matter if I post a text message or image or other file: `System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableArray'1[Discord.Attachment]`

Where Context = `new SocketCommandContext(Client, Message);`

and Message   = `MessageParam as SocketUserMessage;`

Comment: Because it's a collection; you don't ToString a collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have the message as [`SocketMessage`](https://discord.foxbot.me/docs/api/Discord.WebSocket.SocketMessage.html)

You can do `yourSocketMessage.Attachments` to get the collection of attachments that exists in this message, nothing will be in the collection if nothing was attached.

You could iterate through that collection, which should return a [`Attachment`](https://discord.foxbot.me/docs/api/Discord.Attachment.html). And `Attachment` has a `Url` property which you can use alongside with [`System.IO.Path.GetExtension(url)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getextension?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_IO_Path_GetExtension_System_String_)
(Suprisingly, the function has been [proven that it works with url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23228378/is-there-any-way-to-get-the-file-extension-from-a-url))