# Get filename of a file downloaded by asp.net from a redirect

Tags: vb.net, webclient, response-headers

I have this code:

```
Dim Filename = "" 'I NEED TO GET THE FILE NEMAE
Using client As New WebClient()
client.DownloadFile("www.URL.com_that_redirects_to_random_file.pfx", "c:/" & Filename)
End Using
```

If I use

```
client.ResponseHeaders
```

It contains

```
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: "95308f8df644d71:0"
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Sun, 09 May 2021 20:09:40 GMT
Content-Type: application/x-pkcs12
Last-Modified: Sun, 09 May 2021 17:12:55 GMT
Content-Length: 1542
```

But there is not the filaname

So How Can I get the filename of the redirect ?
May I need to touch IIS ?
As I cannot touch the "www.URL.com_that_redirects_to_random_file.pfx" as that server file gets a random string and resirects to a file based on random string get in a db

Comment: Normally, that information would be in the `content-disposition` header, but if you aren't getting that header back, the server may not be dishing it out to begin with.  Perhaps see https://stackoverflow.com/a/13571471/6530134 - it's C#, but you should be able to translate to VB.NET.  Also, if you can, you should avoid using `WebClient`, [it's not recommended for use](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient?view=net-5.0#remarks)

Comment: Maybe there isn't a file name to begin with. You're downloading data that may or may not come from a file. If it gets generated on the fly then there's no file to have a name in the first place.